# 8 digit byte conversion

Tags: java, arrays, byte, concatenation

I'm trying to convert an array of 8 integers (0 or 1) into the java byte type.

e.g.

```
 [1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0] = 10100010
```

i tried searching online, maybe I'm not inputting the right queries? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) to [`set()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#set%28int,%20boolean%29) true/false for specific indices reading array and then convert it to byte array

Comment: great, that was exactly what i was looking for. thanks! I'll accept answer when i'm able to.

Comment: hm so i'm trying to do bitset.set(7); and its giving me an unexpected type error. any suggestions?

Comment: `bitset.set(7, false);` : See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#set%28int,%20boolean%29

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    byte[] bits = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
    byte b = 0;
    for (int i = 0, m = 0x80; i < 8; i++, m >>= 1) {
        if (bits[i] == 1) b |= m;
    }
```

or this one line solution

```
byte b = (byte) Integer.parseInt(Arrays.toString(bits).toString().replaceAll("\\D", ""), 2);
```